# standard limits rigorous proof , $a>1 $, linear function divided by exponential

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to \infty } \frac{x}{a^x}=0$$
where $a>1$

How to prove this in a rigorous way ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: I doubt that what they want us to use , can it be done by epsilon and delta ?

Comment: You should be able to avoid L'hopital using properties of the logarithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a>1 \Rightarrow a=1+p ,p>0 $

for$ x\geq 1 \exists   n\in N , n>1$ such that

$n  \leq  x\leq n+1$ or in other words , $x-1\leq n\leq x$

Now just show $(1+p)^{x}\geq (1+p)^{n}$ using binomial theorem.